# Sbcl "Function Undefined"

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm fairly new to common lisp and have been doing Exercism exercises to get into it.

I'm using debian on wsl2 on windows 10.

I have sbcl 2.1.1 with quicklisp

Here is the file I'm trying to load

```
(defpackage :lillys-lasagna-leftovers
  (:use :cl)
  (:export
   :preparation-time
   :remaining-minutes-in-oven
   :split-leftovers))

(in-package :lillys-lasagna-leftovers)

(defun preparation-time (&rest rest)
  (* 19 (length rest)))
 


(defun remaining-minutes-in-oven (&optional (opt :normal opt-provided))
  (if opt-provided (cond
                     ((eql opt :shorter) 337)
                     ((eql opt :very-short) 137)
                     ((eql opt :longer) 437)
                     ((eql opt :very-long) 537)
                     (t nil))
      opt))
```

Aside from the issues which could arise if the second function is incorrect.
I have tried loading the above file in two ways

1. By entering sbcl and using

   ```
   (load "test-file-name")

   (preparation-time 1 2 3)
   ```
2. By loading the file into sbcl

   ```
   sbcl --load "test-file-name"

   (preparation-time 1 2 3)
   ```

In both cases I get

```
CL-USER(1): (preparation-time)
; in: PREPARATION-TIME
;     (PREPARATION-TIME)
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::PREPARATION-TIME
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     PREPARATION-TIME
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to have a way in which I can test my code locally.

Comment: `(cond ((eql opt 'a) ...) ((eql opt 'b) ...))` can be written `(case opt (a ...) (b ...))`

Comment: Thank you. I did see the option for case, however we had not done it until that point, thus I wanted to use what was available to me at the time.

Nevertheless, thank you for again your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a symbol without a package prefix, the reader uses the current package (and other reader settings) to decide what symbol it refers to. When you start SBCL, the current package is named CL-USER.

Your function is named by the string `PREPARATION-TIME` in a package named `LILLYS-LASAGNA-LEFTOVERS`. If you are in the CL-USER package, and you want to refer to it, you can do this:

- `(lillys-lasagna-leftovers::preparation-time 1 2 3)` - this will work on symbols regardless of their external status
- `(lillys-lasagna-leftovers:preparation-time 1 2 3)` - this syntax with only one colon works because you used `:export` to make the symbol external

If you'd like to refer to `preparation-time` without a package prefix, there are a few options:

- `(use-package :lilys-lasagna-leftovers)` will make the current package inherit all external symbols, which includes `preparation-time` - this can fail if a different, non-eq symbol is already accessible by the same name
- `(import 'lilys-lasagna-leftovers:preparation)` will make that symbol present in the current package, so it can be referred to without a prefix - this can fail if a different, non-eq symbol is already accessible by the same name
- `(shadowing-import 'lilys-lasagna-leftovers:preparation)` will make that symbol present in the current package, and additionally override any previously accessible symbols with the same name
- `(in-package :lilys-lasagna-leftovers)` will change the value of `*package*` so symbol lookups without a package prefix are relative to your package

Of all these options, if I were working on this project, I would most likely use `in-package`. The other options have their most appropriate uses as well, but you can usually start with `in-package` and move on to other things as the need arises.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
(lillys-lasagna-leftovers:preparation-time)
```

The function `PREPARATION-TIME` has been exported from package `LILLYS-LASAGNA-LEFTOVERS`.